# Firebase is not sending otp properly

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app that has the feature to get an OTP, and I've used firebase OTP feature (Authenticate with Firebase on Android using a Phone Number) but unfortunately some-time I'm facing issue like I'm not getting otp from firebase also its not giving any errors at same time. I don't know what was the mistake i did.Need help to solve this issue also I've tried some samples its working properly but when i try to integrate in my project firebase is not sending otp.I want post mobile number to firestore with users current country code for ex(+91,+888).

This what I've tried in my project so far:

```
package com.example.NewActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.aayushchaubey.meetdax.R;
import com.example.activity.HomeActivity;
import com.example.activity.PhoneNumberLogin;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseTooManyRequestsException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthSettings;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class LoginWithMobileNumber extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText phoneNo_Edt;
    Button loginBtn;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private static final String TAG = "FirebasePhoneNumAuth";

    PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
    String mVerificationId;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mobileno_verification);

        phoneNo_Edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneNoEdt);
        loginBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.phoneNoLoginBtn);
        phoneNo_Edt.setSingleLine();
        firebaseAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        addOnClickListener();

        mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
                // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
                // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
                //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
                // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
                //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without
                //     user action.
                Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);

                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
                // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.
                Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e);

                if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                    // Invalid request
                    // ...
                } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                    // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                    // ...
                }

                // Show a message and update the UI
                // ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                                   PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
                // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
                // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
                // by combining the code with a verification ID.
                Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verificationId);

                // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
                mVerificationId = verificationId;
                mResendToken = token;

                // ...
            }
        };


    }

    private void addOnClickListener() {

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendSms();
            }
        });
    }

    public void sendSms(){
        String phoneNumber=phoneNo_Edt.getText().toString();
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                60,                 // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks

    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();

                            if(mVerificationId!=null){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VerifyOtp.class);
                                intent.putExtra("verificationcode",mVerificationId);
                                startActivity(intent);                            }

                            // ...
                        } else {
                            // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                // The verification code entered was invalid
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using Firebase OTP verification in my application and after spending a week solving different scenarios I understood followings. May be it will help in your case as well.

**Consider following scenario.**

1. When you call `PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber()`, most of the times `Firebase` will send OTP and our code will receive `onCodeSent` callback. After that, if device recieves OTP, sdk will 
   call `onVerificationCompleted` or `onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut` according to the timeout value you passed in the parameters.
2. (May be this could be your case) Sometimes when you call `PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber()`, sdk will call `onCodeSent` method but device does not receive any OTP. And meanwhile, sdk will auto verify phone number and call `onVerificationCompleted` directly without sending any OTP.

So you should cosider above scenario and decide accordingly.

I am still not sure if this answer will satisfy your scenario or not but it will surely help you to understand things better.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallBack = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();

        // In case OTP is received
        if (code != null) {
            otpTxt.setText(code);
            verifyCode(code);
        } else {
        // In case OTP is not received
            signInWithCredentials(phoneAuthCredential);
        }
    }
```